# How to get facebook id of friends

Tags: ios, facebook, social-framework

I want to get facebookid of my friends. But seems like its sending different id's

The situation is i have a friends name "abc" when i loads the friends list then i am getting following response for friend "abc" from facebook

```
<__NSCFArray 0xce76290>(
{
    id = 668201987254085;
    name = "abc";
}
)
```

and my facebook id is "123764734754"returned by facebook

i am using below code for this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
SLRequest *friendsListRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                                   requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET
                                                              URL:URLIFY(@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends")
                                                      parameters:nil];
friendsListRequest.account = facebookAccount;
[friendsListRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
    if (responseData) {
        NSLog(@"Got a response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData
                                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
        if (urlResponse.statusCode >= 200 && urlResponse.statusCode < 300) {
            NSError *jsonError = nil;
            NSDictionary *friendsListData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData
                                                                            options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                                              error:&jsonError];
            if (jsonError) {
                NSLog(@"Error parsing friends list: %@", jsonError);
            } else {
                self.userList = friendsListData[@"data"];
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"HTTP %ld returned", (long)urlResponse.statusCode);
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"ERROR Connecting");
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
    });
}];
```

But when i am logging in using user name "abc" then for abc (current login user) i am getting different id say "10008772786278"

same thing when i login then i got my facebook id"123764734754" but when my friend "abc" login then in his friends list response they got my id "897349579554"

why this thing happen? how to get same facebook id of the user that is returned after when he login

Answer (score 6):

Please Try this code.

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"basic_info"] allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error){
        NSLog(@"Error :%@",error);
        if (session.isOpen && !error) {

            [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" parameters:nil HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,id result, NSError *error){

                if (!error) {
                    NSLog(@"result %@",result);
                    [array_firendList addObjectsFromArray:[result valueForKey:@"data"]];

                    NSLog(@"count %ld",(unsigned long)[array_firendList count]);
                }
 }];
```

Answer (score 1):

Facebook recently changed a lot of stuff, see here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

See "App-scoped User IDs", you don´t get the real IDs anymore:

> To better protect people's information, when people log into a version
>   of your app that has been upgraded to use Graph API v2.0, Facebook
>   will now issue an app-scoped ID rather than that person's orginal ID

Also important:

> The /me/friends endpoint no longer includes the full list of a
>   person's friends. Instead, it now returns the list of that person's
>   friends who are also using your app.

To make sure you always get an App Scoped ID, use `/v2.0/{object}` instead of `/{object}`. For example, to get the ID of the logged in user you can use `/v2.0/me`, for getting the friend list you can use `/v2.0/me/friends`. This is only necessary if your App is created before May 2014, if you created it later it will only use v2.0 anyway.

Another hint: make sure you get the IDs (with `/me` or `/me/friends`) on the same platform and of course with the same App, don´t compare the IDs you get with the Graph API Explorer (for example) with the ones you get in the App.

Comment: i am adding functionality of login via facebook. When i login then facebook return me say "1234" facebook id and then i save it as userid in my backend, but my friend will get my id "78978" so if he want to check stuff of mine using id "78978" when he will not find as "78978" is not registered in my app. so how to fix this issue then ?

Comment: forget about the /me - you will also get an app scoped user id for that call.

Comment: i thought the app scoped ids are the same with /me and /me/friends, but if that´s not the case i don´t think there is a workaround.

Comment: When i login into facebook then i am getting below uinique data so i am using uid as my backend database userid properties: {
    ACPropertyFullName = "myusername";
    ACUIAccountSimpleDisplayName = "myusername";
    ACUIDisplayUsername = "myusername@yahoo.in";
    uid = 154001632508970;
}

Comment: but my friends see my id "8937497847493" so if they want to check post of mine using id "8937497847493" then there is nothing as no user is registered with "8937497847493" id so either when i login i should be return d "8937497847493" id that i can use for login in my app

Comment: yeah, if the app scoped id of the logged in user is different from the one you get with the friends connection, it will be impossible to connect them, unfortunately. i have asked in the facebook developers group on facebook, but since you already tested it, i doubt that it helps.

Comment: is there any way to get app scoped id(not cononical id) of logged in user? so that on the time of login into backend i should use app scope id rather than cononical id

Comment: for apps created after april 2014, you should ONLY get the app scoped id for the logged in user. if that is not the case, you should upgrade your app to v2.0.

Comment: i will edit my answer to add more information about that

Comment: still getting same problem, I think facebook is doing useless changes

Comment: while i login i got origional id but for my friends get my app-scope id what is this? when facebook wil be down like orkut? i am waiting for this

Comment: you could try to create a completely new app for testing. are you sure you login with the same app and on the same platform? where/how do you get your original id?

Comment: i have just created a new app and changed the facebookappid in my projects. and then logged in with my account then i get my appscopeid like "12345678" and no friends as other friends are not using this app. so after that one of my friend login into same app and then get one friend (me) but he see my appscope id = "563546345" but it should be"12345678" that i got from facebook when i logged in

Comment: tottly harrashed change by facebook

Comment: as per ur suggestion i am using "/v2.0" now. But i have one doubt that when i login with ACAccountType then social.framework might not be using "/v2.0". as ios7 is not changed after facebook change. is that can be the reason?

Comment: there should be no need to use /v2.0 on new apps. not sure why you still get different IDs though...